# PHP Notice with page URL

Tags: php, error-handling

I have received many PHP Notice in log, but i want to know what page URL where happened Notice, how can i log this info?

```
[29-Nov-2012 13:58:29] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /usr/home/sdf/data/www/sdfsdf.com/core/test.php on line 156
```

I want to log any info, when get NOTICE, how to log it?

Comment: It is in your error log! `/usr/home/sdf/data/www/sdfsdf.com/core/test.php on line 156`

Comment: Am I missing something?  The page in your notice is `test.php`.

Comment: Error happened at `test.php` on line 156

Comment: see your access log if there isn't the referer in error log

Comment: Show line 156. We can't tell you what's wrong with it without seeing it.

Comment: it`s php file, i need to know what page used, http://test.com/test_page.php i have many pages with this php file.

Comment: I think what the OP is trying to say is that he needs to know the root page of the stack trace to see which page was requested to cause the problem in the *possibly* included file `test.php`.

Comment: i knwo that i have problem, but i dont know what happend there, because in tests all good, but when users acess pages, in some pages gets notice

Comment: Turn ON the errors in PHP and errors will start appear in browser. You can start testing again.

Comment: I turn, but i don`t have any errors, its happend on some user pages, i want to know what pages are

Comment: I'm not sure I would enable errors globally, but if he has session controls he could output error data for only his account.

Comment: why don't you just fix the issue?

Comment: i cant understand error, code simple, all works great, but in some case not, want to find this pages

Comment: Did you just downvote every answer, swamplogger7?  If so, explain yourself.

Comment: Note down the date and time from `error_log` (e.g. `29-Nov-2012 13:58:29`) and locate the exact date and time in `access_log`.

Comment: i don't downvote, thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up something to capture error/debug info as it happens, but not show it to the entire world.   Not sure if you have session management built in to this application, but you may want to add some basic controls for this exercise.

Sometimes errors are harder to track down if you use functions that are included on multiple pages.  The error may appear to happen on the parent page, but is actually triggered in the function, which is included on another page.  The error line numbers can be misleading in this case.

If you have intermittent errors that you aren't able to immediately isolate, it may help to get some feedback on what's happening in your script(s).  Here's a rough example of how to do some basic debugging in functions:

```
function get_func_argNames($funcName) 
{
    $f = new ReflectionFunction($funcName);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($f->getParameters() as $param) 
    {
        $result[] = $param->name;
    }
    return $result;
}


function myCoolFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
{

    $debug = false;

    $php_function_args  = implode(', ',get_func_argNames(__FUNCTION__));

    $_debug_txt = "<b><span style='color:blue;'>function</span> <span style='color:darkblue;'>" .__FUNCTION__. "</span></b>($php_function_args)";

    if ($debug)
    {
        EmailAppDev($_debug_txt);
    }

        // myCoolFunction
        $x = $arg1 + $arg2 + $arg3;
        return $x

 }
```

Ideally you'll have a session account that can control who $debug is enabled for.

If you aren't using functions, you'll need to set up something similar in strategic areas of your scripts, to find out when and where things are going sour.

Without having your entire app to look at it's pretty hard to give specifics.

Comment: If there is an url rewrite that point to test.php? What is the URL? (I think is the original question)

Comment: He isn't providing us with much info - but yes, that could be a possibility.  He could also be including a file on multiple pages, and the error misleadingly points to the parent page.

Comment: @chumkiu PHP error log will have the correct file even there is a URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correlate the timestamps in the php error log with your web server access log.

Or, you could tail -f the log and trigger random pages.

Or, set a custom error handler to log all sorts of data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
function myErrorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ){

    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;

}

set_error_handler( "myErrorHandler" );
```

Comment: I tried error handler, but it`s dont work on all errors, only on custom trigger_error?

Comment: Showing the entire world application error data isn't a good idea.  This would work fine if he has session controls where he can enable error reporting for only his account.

Comment: This is just an example of how to set up an error handler... don't follow it verbatim.

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php to get a nice stack trace.

Comment: This should work for all errors. Please make sure error_handling is turned on for all error levels.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for turning on error_reporting... Just make sure you suppress the message with a custom error handler (to a log) instead of printing it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to compare you php notice times to your webservers access log in order to find out the URL which caused that notice.

The notice actually does not look like URL dependent.
It indicates, that you're trying to cast a "type" array to a string which happens when you do something like this:

```
$array = array( 'foo', 'bar' );

echo $array;
$string = 'test' . $array;
printf ( 'foo %s', $array );
```

Comment: Yep, please explain.. There's nothing wrong in my answer and it adresses your question. Always glad to help those who actually want it

Comment: Someone maybe "swamprunner7", zinged every answer in this thread.  All of them were helpful in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

To find this error *in particular*, you could do this to figure out what's wrong (including printing a backtrace using `debug_backtrace`):

```
if (is_string($var)) {
    //Then it's OK - do whatever you were doing on line 156
} else {
    //Something's wrong! Let's log it to some file!
    ob_start();
    var_dump($var);
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
    echo "\n----------------------------------------------\n";
    $debugContent = ob_get_clean();

    $logHandle = fopen("wrong_var_type.log", "a");
    if ($logHandle !== false) {
        fwrite($logHandle, $debugContent . "\n");
    }
    @fclose($logHandle);
}
```

Alternatively, use a logger:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10800296/247893